# Is there an Oracle SQL query that aggregates multiple rows into one row?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation, string-concatenation

I have a table that looks like this:

```
A 1 
A 2 
B 1 
B 2
```

And I want to produce a result set that looks like this:

```
A 1 2 
B 1 2
```

Is there a SQL statement that will do this?  I am using Oracle.

Related questions:

- [Returning multiple rows from a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887870/sql-select-returning-multiple-rows-from-one-table-row)  My question is close to the opposite of this question.
- [Use LINQ to concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614542/use-linq-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-row-csv-property)  This is exactly what I want to do, but without LINQ.

Comment: See similar question [advice-using-pivot-table-in-oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365238/advice-using-pivot-table-in-oracle)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492563/oracle-combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-valu

Answer (score 28):

(**WARNING** - `WM_CONCAT` is an unsupported function that was removed in version 12c. Unless you're using a very old database, you should avoid this function. You should probably use `LISTAGG` instead.)

---

It depends on the version of Oracle you're using.  If it supports the wm_concat() function, then you can simply do something like this:

```
SELECT field1, wm_concat(field2) FROM YourTable GROUP BY field2;
```

wm_concat() basically works just like [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in MySQL.  It may not be documented, so fire up ye olde sqlplus and see if it's there.

If it *isn't* there, then you'll want to implement something equivalent yourself.  You can find some instructions on how to do this in the [string aggregation page](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php) at oracle-base.com.

Comment: Note that wmsys.wm_concat is undocumented and unsupported.

Answer (score 23):

Pretty old topic, but it could help others since Oracle improved in the mean time.

The [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) function is what you are looking for (in 11g at least)

Comment: select distinct c1, listagg(c2, ' ') within group (order by c2) over (partition by c1) as c2_list from table;

Comment: url is expired. Those who want to check try this out https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 9):

In `Oracle 10g+`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable
        MODEL
        PARTITION BY
                (grouper)
        DIMENSION BY
                (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grouper ORDER BY id) AS rn)
        MEASURES
                (val, val AS group_concat, 0 AS mark)
        RULES SEQUENTIAL ORDER (
                group_concat[rn > 1] ORDER BY rn = group_concat[CV() - 1] || ', ' || val[CV()],
                mark[ANY] ORDER BY rn = PRESENTV(mark[CV() + 1], 0, 1)
                )
        )
WHERE   mark = 1
ORDER BY
        grouper
```

See this article in my blog for explanations:

- [**`GROUP_CONCAT` in `Oracle 10g`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/05/group_concat-in-oracle-10g/)

Comment: You are totally dependent on mytable being sorted by rn. If it is not sorted you'll get an "ORA-32637: Self cyclic rule in sequential order MODEL". So this variant is buggy. You may want to read another model clause variant on my blog: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/05/string-aggregation-with-model-clause.html

Comment: @Rob: `rn` here is just an alias for `ROW_NUMBER()`. I copied it from my article (which used a `CTE` as a rowsource) but didn't put it into the table. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if, for instance, you used another analytic function with a different order by, and that accompanying WINDOW SORT operation is executed last, you get the aforementioned error. So you still have to use ordered rule evaluation to make this idea work.

Comment: @Rob: right again, updated, checked with `6 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grouper ORDER BY rno) AS rn`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like :

```
SELECT
    field1,
    RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(XMLAgg(XMLElement("x", field2) ORDER BY field2), '<x>'), '</x>', ' ')) AS field2s
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY field1
```

Freely inspired by an answer [found in this Oracle forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=339792#1229525).

**EDIT:** this solution proved ***very*** resources intensive with requests involving something like 10<sup>5</sup> rows. I ended up replacing this by custom aggregate functions as [suggested by John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row/1120904#1120904).

Answer (score 4):

If you have got 10g, then you have to go through the function below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_separated_value (input_val  in  number)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  return_text  VARCHAR2(10000) := NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT col2 FROM table_name WHERE col1 = input_val) LOOP
    return_text := return_text || ' ' || x.col2 ;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN return_text;
END;
/
```

So, you can do like:

```
select col1, get_separated_value(col1) from table_name
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19ba9/1)

If you have got oracle 11g, you can use [listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) :

```
SELECT 
    age,
    LISTAGG(name, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) "names"
FROM table_x
GROUP BY age
```

[Fiddle here for Listagg](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81e177/1)

Answer (score 2):

User defined aggregate functions: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/user_def_agg.html

Just copy/paste and use it. Works on 9i.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a , COLLECT(b) FROM foo GROUP BY a
```

very useful when used in pl/sql - can be casted to a user defined collection.

Comment: When I tried it on an 11g database the CAST was required. But I gave you +1 because I didn't know the COLLECT function existed - Oracle adds so many features it's impossible to keep up.