# Group_concat MySQL function's equivalent in Oracle

Tags: oracle, string-aggregation

Hi i am looking for a function same group_concat of mysql in oracle 
or some functionality

Comment: Google ftw: http://halisway.blogspot.com/2006/08/oracle-groupconcat-updated-again.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Tom Kyte's STRAGG function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle `wm_concat()` function