# SQL query to return multiple row into a single row and column of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would an example table as follows:

TableA

```
ID / Name / Sport

001 / Max / Football

005 / Steven / Badminton

006 / Cindy / Swimming

001 / Max / Tennis

001 / Max / Rugby

005 / Steven / Football
```

I would like a SQL query statement to return the result as follows:

```
ID / Name / SportList

001 / Max / Football; Tennis; Rugby

005 / Steven / Badminton; Football

006 / Cindy / Swimming
```

Sorry, I have to use '/' to differentiate the column. Unable to attached a file due to low reputation.

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
 Id,
 Name,
 GROUP_CONCAT(Sport  ORDER BY Sport SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM TableA
GROUP BY  Id, Name
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25421/4)

Answer (score 0):

There is no DB agnostic way to achieve this function.

[How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)

for Oracle:

[Group_concat MySQL function's equivalent in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127287/group-concat-mysql-functions-equivalent-in-oracle)

[Is there any function in oracle similar to group_concat in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-like-group-concat-of-mysql)

---