# How to Merge fields after query, i know CONCAT, but not this way

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

[image]

[image]

I know the way to merge field in

- MySQL: `CONCAT( )`
- Oracle: `CONCAT( )`, `||`
- SQL Server: `+

but...
I wanna merge AFTER query, is it possible?

Comment: Which target database system?

Comment: Do you really need a solution for all 3 different database products?

Comment: SQL Server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings and others...

Comment: MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Oracle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127287/group-concat-mysql-functions-equivalent-in-oracle

Comment: Sorry, I can only mark duplicate for one database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can edit after you mark as duplicate and add more posts...

Comment: i use Oracle, thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

**MySQL** using `group_concat`:

```
select a.name,
    a.opcode,
    group_concat(month order by b.pk separator ', ') as months
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.opcode = b.opcode
group by a.name, a.opcode;
```

**Oracle** using `listagg`:

```
select a.name,
    a.opcode,
    listagg(month,', ') within group (order by b.pk) as months
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.opcode = b.opcode
group by a.name, a.opcode;
```

**SQL Server** using `for xml path` and `stuff`:

```
select a.*,
    stuff((
        select ', ' + month from tableb b
        where a.opcode = b.opcode
        order by pk 
        for xml path(''), type
        ).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '') as months
from tablea a;
```

Comment: Your SQL Server example is broken in two ways. First it will fail with special XML characters like & and <, and it does not specify an explicit order as the other examples do. That being said, the question is too broad as each specific vendor case has been answered in other SO questions already.

Comment: @Lucero - Thanks for the feedback. I missed the order by clause. About special character, I don't think there is need to handle that as no month will contain special characters.

Comment: People looking at this question will most likely not want to concat specifically month names... not a good answer for the Q&A format of SO.

Comment: @Lucero - I've added a note to the answer. Ironically the questions to which it's tagged as duplicate also do not have answer that consider the special characters. :)

Comment: This one does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings/5031297#5031297 (and in some of the other T-SQL answers people have made aware of the issue as well)

Comment: @Lucero - Great. I have mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: Why don't you just fix the code sample? ;)

Comment: @Lucero - Updated. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Lucero That was good from you , he fix it.