# Merging Query Result into single row - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, string-aggregation

Can I do like this in oracle,.? I have some data like this:

```
No | Data |
===========
 1 | A    |
 1 | B    |
 1 | C    |
 1 | D    |
```

Is there any query that can produce a result like this,.?

```
No | Data       |
=================
 1 | A, B, C, D |
```

Many thanks :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Comment: This question has been asked very many times on SO.  The thread I link to above contains all the common answers.  you will find at least one which will help you whichever version of Oracle you're using.

Comment: This technique is called `string aggregation`. See the questions tagges as such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this page](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm) shows what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/682458/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( ID, DATA ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'B' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'C' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'D' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'E' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'F' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID,
       LISTAGG( DATA, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY DATA ) AS AGGREGATED_DATA
FROM   TEST
GROUP BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/682458/1/0)**:

```
| ID | AGGREGATED_DATA |
|----|-----------------|
|  1 |         A,B,C,D |
|  2 |             E,F |
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle we can use `wm_concat` function. Here is the query for example above:

```
SELECT no, wm_concat(data) from table group by no
```

reference: [wm_concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row)

Comment: Note that wm_concat is undocumented, so use at your own risk.

Comment: Very nice:with my_table as
(
select 1 num, 'A' col from dual union
select 1 num, 'B' col from dual union
select 1 num, 'C' col from dual union
select 1 num, 'D' col from dual union
select 2 num, 'E' col from dual union
select 2 num, 'F' col from dual union
select 2 num, 'G' col from dual union
select 2 num, 'H' col from dual 
)
select num, wm_concat(col) 
from my_table
group by num
;

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   no,
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (d, data|| ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') data
from 
   table_name
group by 
   no
;
```