# Sum and Group by dynamically in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement in which there are four parameters. p1,p2,p3,p4. User can enter any of these either single or combinations.I want to display only the columns which he enters by summing and grouping.Other columns should be excluded.How can i do this?

Comment: User enters data through an application (web, desktop, command line, doesn't matter). You should build your query dynamically in the application, this is not an PLSQL question at all...

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what do you mean by *summing and grouping* ? Do you need to do some pivoting ?

Comment: I want to know how to build that query..Because he can enter 24 combinations.For eg if he enters p1,p2 i need to display only those by Select p1,p2 from the table group by p1,p2.like wise p1,p3 he can enter.p1,p2,p3,p4 als0.Jus -1.Hop i explained my requirement clearly

Comment: :You can do it with PL/SQL block .Dynamically create your query based on your input

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may well work for you *(I'm not 100% certain because your question is very vague)*

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN :p1 = 0 THEN p1 ELSE NULL END AS p1,
  CASE WHEN :p2 = 0 THEN p2 ELSE NULL END AS p2,
  CASE WHEN :p3 = 0 THEN p3 ELSE NULL END AS p3,
  CASE WHEN :p4 = 0 THEN p4 ELSE NULL END AS p4
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN :p1 = 0 THEN p1 ELSE NULL END,
  CASE WHEN :p2 = 0 THEN p2 ELSE NULL END,
  CASE WHEN :p3 = 0 THEN p3 ELSE NULL END,
  CASE WHEN :p4 = 0 THEN p4 ELSE NULL END
```

Be aware, however, that SQL often performs quite poorly with this type of query.

For each and every fixed query, a separate plan is compiled.  The algorithm use to generate the results is fixed in place at that point.  It is not re-compiled when your parameters are changed.

This is important because, depending on your indexes, `GROUP BY p1, p2` could results in a fundamentally different plan from using `GROUP BY p3, p4`.

Because of that it can often be much more performant to re-generate the SQL statement in code.

Rather than asking SQL to use the parameters to pick which fields are aggregated, use the parameters to write a brand new SQL statement, and execute that new SQL statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use something like group concat in mysql this can help 
[Is there an Oracle SQL query that aggregates multiple rows into one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using dynamic SQL. In dynamic SQL you can first construct your select statement base on the input parameters and then execute the query using e.g. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Please read the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm) on how to use dynamic SQL.