# How to get all usersnames in a single sql row

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Oracle SQL query that aggregates multiple rows into one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row)

i have the below output for my sql query to get the users details from oracle table

```
   Select distinct userid from Scope1

USERID 
Rakesh 
Admin
```

i want the output to be as below so that i can do my queries even easier. please help me.

```
USERID
'Rakesh','Admin'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using **LISTAGG**, Tim Hall has excellent documentation on this [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)

```
   select LISTAGG(''''||userid||'''', ',')
   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY userid) userid
   from Scope1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7810/2)

Comment: this works for Oracle 11G but i use Oracke 10g, any alternative please . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that will do a loop in your query. The function will return a comma seperated value of the data you need. Something like:

```
str1 := '';
for rec in (select distinct userid from Scope1) 
loop
  str1 := str1 || rec.userid || ', ';
end loop;
str1 := substr(str1, 1, length(str1) - 2);
```

Comment: it is saying it as an invalid query

Comment: you should put that in a function: create or replace function fnc as....

Comment: check also this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5009.htm

Answer (score 0):

Below query selects the data in comma separated format:

```
SELECT 
   RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E, userid || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()'), ',') AS UserID
FROM Scope1 ;
```

How about using wm_concat:

```
SELECT wm_concat(''''||userid||'''') FROM Scope1;
```

Comment: thanks bro it worked but i also wanted them with '' like 'Rakesh', 'Admin'

Comment: Please check the answer altered.

Comment: should it be SELECT wm_concat(''''||userid||'''') (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E, userid || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()'), ','); if so it is not working brother

Comment: `SELECT wm_concat(''''||userid||'''') FROM Scope1;` is working in oralce 11G. Which is your oracle version?

Comment: okay... Please check the link: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the inbuilt LISTAGG function:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm