# SQL Query to return all column values in a single row

Tags: sql, plsql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Oracle SQL query that aggregates multiple rows into one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row)

I have a table (Employee).

Employee

```
ID   Name   Salary  

1    Steve  10000

2    Buck   15000

3    Dan    10000 

4    Dave   10000
```

I need to return all employee names who have the salary of $10000, employee names are delimited by Plus signs – including one on the beginning and end. I can do this using a cursor and add all the employee names iterate through the cursor. But is there a way to return this using a single query? In this above example i need the result as +Steve+Dan+Dave+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on string aggregation functions.

For example in Oracle 11g Release 2, you can do somthing like :

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('+', LISTAGG(Employee.Name, '+')), '+') FROM Employee WHERE Salary >= 10000
```

Comment: I'm seeing this error.. ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Comment: Sorry, I edited my example. (CONCAT() only accepts 2 strings.)

Comment: For some reason My toad is not recognizing the keyword LISTAGG.. i'm seeing this error when I execute the query above.. ORA-00904: "LISTAGG": invalid identifier

Comment: Looks like we don't have the Oracle 11g Relese 2 yet. We have the older version of 11g

Comment: OK, have a look on wm_concat http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#wm_concat