# Concating rows in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table named Dummy as shown below:

```
No.   Name
1     ABC
2     NMD
2     SDSDS
1     23ererer
```

Now i wanted to concat all `Name` column with a given number

For ex. say No. is `1` i want `ABC23ererer` as  my output

This is to be done in ORACLE(SQL) without using  PL-SQL.

How can this be done?

Comment: do you want to concat all names in the name column with the same number?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row can give some hints.

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help...

```
select NO,
  listagg(NAME, ',') within group (order by NAME) as name
from TableName
group by NO
```

Or else check [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)

Answer (score 1):

> LISTAGG is not supported in oracle10g. If you have 10g i think the following query will help you.

```
select No, rtrim(Name,',') Name
       from ( select No
      , Name, rn
         from yourtable
               model
                      partition by (No)
                        dimension by (row_number() over
                                     (partition by No order by Name) rn
                                    )
                       measures     (cast(Name as varchar2(40)) Name)
                       rules
                       ( Name[any] order by rn desc = Name[cv()]||''||Name[cv()+1]
                       )
              )
        where rn = 1
        order by NO
```

see for your [demo in sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a5d1/12)

Comment: you have ask's tom `stragg` since 9i [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:15637744429336)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "No.", LISTAGG(Name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "No.") AS Name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY "No.";
```

Answer (score -4):

try this :

```
SELECT Number+' '+
Name FROM table_name
```

Comment: Did you look at the example he gave?

Comment: That's not valid SQL (neither in Oracle nor standard SQL)